# Implementing Two Factor Authentication on Liferay DXP 7.2

Tags: liferay, two-factor-authentication

I am using Liferay DXP 7.2 and I need to implement Two Factor Authentication.
My problem is that when a user logs in into the portal, he can immediately access all the private pages.
I'm searching for a way to log in, redirect the user to a page where he needs to submit the code sent to him and only after that grant access to the private pages.
I thought of an idea to add and remove roles in the first and second authentication but I was required to find a better way without changing the user's role.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a portal filter which checks for the second authentication , 
if second authentication is not done you can redirect to a page  where second authentication will happen. with this at anytime second authentication is kept in check .
After second authentication you can save the it in session or db as per your requirement and clear it on logout/session timeout .
For Portal filter you can refer below.
https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/servlet-filters

Thanks

Comment: It means that after the second authentication, every time the user asks for a private page url the servlet filter checks if he was authenticated for the second time?

Comment: Yes because in case session timeout is happened then on refresh u should be able tell user to re-authenticate and also user can copy page saved urls

Answer (score 0):

If you want two different levels of access, you'll end up adding and removing roles one way or another - most likely. I recommend not going the route of implementing your own permission checker (while it's possible to do so, it's quite complex and it's easy to make mistakes, leading to unintended sideeffects.

If you want a single level of access, but two factor authentication, my recommendation is to go through a SSO system that can do so. As soon as you're authenticated, you can grant the full permissions and access the portal.